# Adding computed decorator causes a TypeError

Tags: babeljs, mobx

I can't use `@computed`. If I run my code bellow I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: An element descriptor's .kind property must be either "method" or "field", but a decorator created an element descriptor with .kind "undefined"
    at _toElementDescriptor (app.js:46281)
    at _toElementFinisherExtras (app.js:46283)
    at _decorateElement (app.js:46273)
    at app.js:46269
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _decorateClass (app.js:46269)
    at _decorate (app.js:46251)
    at Module../src/App/stores/UserStore.js (app.js:46301)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/App/stores/index.js (index.js:1)
```

And here is my `UserStore.js` file:

```
import { 
  configure,
  runInAction,
  observable,
  action,
  computed
} from 'mobx'
import API from '../api'

configure({ enforceActions: 'observed' })

class UserStore {
  @observable users
  @observable state
  @observable currPage
  @observable hasMore
  @observable errors

  constructor() {
    this.users = []
    this.state = 'loading'
    this.currPage = 0
    this.hasMore = true
    this.errors = []
  }

  @action
  addUser = (user) => {
    this.users.shift(user)
  }

  @action
  addUsers = (users) => {
    this.users = this.users.concat(users)
  }

  @action
  async fetchUsers () {
    let req;
    try {
      req = await API.allUsers()
      runInAction(() => {
        this.state = 'done'
        this.addUsers(req.body.users || [])
        this.hasMore = (req.body.users && req.body.users.length) ? true : false
        this.currPage = this.currPage + 1
      })
    } catch (e) {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.state = 'error'
        this.hasMore = false
      })
    }
  }

  @computed
  get females () {
    return this.users.filter(user => user.gender === 'female')
  }

  @computed
  get males () {
    return this.users.filters(user => user.gender === 'male')
  }
}

const store = new UserStore();
export default store;
```

If I remove `@computed` the application loads.

Comment: The decorators proposal has gone through massive changes. Your transpiler is likely out of date.

Comment: I'm using babel 7 with `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`, `transform-class-properties` and `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` plugins.

Comment: Check the transpiled code by running babel from the command line. See if it creates the expected output.

Comment: But the actions work ok. If that was a problem wouldn't the actions be an issue too?

Comment: That's a good point but method and property decorators are not the same. Maybe there is a bug in mobx. Maybe they are configuring the descriptor incorrectly.

Comment: Solved it. You was right. Thank you so much without your push in the right direction I'd have never found the solution.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for my error was incorrect `.babelrc` configuration with Babel 7.

**Failing**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "decoratorsBeforeExport": true } ],
    "transform-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

**Working**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true } ],
    [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {
      "loose": true
    }],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hope the wording tweak is cool. `legacy` is the "old" way, it's just that MobX doesn't support the "new" way yet (https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/pull/1732).